# Can you distribute the kernel into a matrix of linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For some injective linear transformation $\varphi$ defined as $M_2(\mathbb{R}) \to M_2(\mathbb{R})$, then $\varphi_2$ is some new linear transformation defined as $$
\varphi_2(X) = \begin{pmatrix}
\varphi(A) & \varphi(B) \\\\
 \varphi(C) & \varphi(D)
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $X = \begin{pmatrix} A&B \\\\ 
C&D\end{pmatrix}$ and $A, B, C, D \in M_2(\mathbb{R})$

I want to show that the Ker$(\varphi_2)$ is also injective given that $\varphi$ is injective.

I have so far that if $X \in \text{Ker}(\varphi_2)$ then$$
\text{Ker}(\varphi_2(X)) = \text{Ker}\left(\begin{pmatrix}
        \varphi(A) & \varphi(B)\\\\ \varphi(C) & \varphi(D)
    \end{pmatrix}\right)
    = \begin{pmatrix}
        \text{Ker}(\varphi(A)) & \text{Ker}(\varphi(B))\\\\ \text{Ker}(\varphi(C)) & \text{Ker}(\varphi(D))
    \end{pmatrix}
    = \begin{pmatrix}
        O_2 & O_2\\\\O_2 & O_2
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then since $\text{Ker}(\varphi_2(X)) = O_4$ then $X=O_4$, making it is also injective.

The part that feels wrong is when I distribute the Ker into the matrix of linear transformations. I am not sure how to prove this is okay, or if there is another way to go about this line of thinking.

Comment: Hi, I think the notation $\ker (\phi_2(X))$ is kind of confusing you. Recall that $\ker$ is something we associate to maps, but here you are associating $\ker$ to a object of the range of the map instead. Procced by simply assuming that $X\in \ker(\phi_2)$ and I believe you will quickly get to what you want to prove. Cheers!

Comment: And you will see it merely comes from the following fact: Let $E$ be a vector space (e.g. your $ M_2(\mathbb{R})$) and $F:=E^4$ (your $ M_4(\mathbb{R})$). Then $0_F=(0_E,0_E,0_E,0_E).$